# Sphinx PHP API EscapeString() function doesn't work for SphinxQL?

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

I found the following function in the Sphinx PHP API code:

```
function sphinxapi_EscapeString($string)
{
    $from = ['\\', '(', ')', '|', '-', '!', '@', '~', '"', '&', '/', '^', '$', '=', '<'];
    $to   = ['\\\\', '\(', '\)', '\|', '\-', '\!', '\@', '\~', '\"', '\&', '\/', '\^', '\$', '\=', '\<'];

    return str_replace($from, $to, $string);
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work properly because when I use strings with certain characters in them in queries Sphinx throws exceptions.

An example is the quote character `"`. `EscapeString()` puts a backslash `\` in front of it, but Sphinx throws an exception saying:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 index my_index: syntax error, unexpected $end near ''' in ..

If I add two more backslashes, making it `\\\"`, then no error is thrown.

What's the deal here? Why isn't `EscapeString()` working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent shared your exact code, but I wonder if you JUST calling this function, need to escape as per SQL rules too.

`EscapeString` ONLY escapes the query to escape the Extended Syntax charactors.

Thats all that is required in the API, as the `Query`/`AddQuery` function takes the query directly.

But in SphinxQL the query string is inside a SQL statement, **so the string needs 'SQL String' escaping before being embedded in the statement** (whether or not you ALSO escape like EscapeString does). PDO can do it automatically if you use prepared statements, otherwise use the PDO `quote` function.

(A Query like `SELECT ... MATCH('one \" ')` isnt escaped propelly, as the slash is 'swallowed' by the SQL parser, not making it through to the Full text Query parser)

Comment: That does indeed appear to be the issue. I've found binding parameters to a prepared statement with PDO does not work with Sphinx (no search results are returned). Others posted this on the Sphinx forum as well, so it must be a bug. But modifying the Sphinx escape function as shown in this answer seems to fix the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7171719/1101095

Comment: Prepared Statements do work with sphinx just fine. I've recently started using them. I suspect using them incorrectly. I still would suggest keeping the two escape functions seperate. ie use EscapeString AND pdo:quote - as they escape different things. Also EscapeString as it stands isn't Multi-Byte safe.

Comment: Prepared statements work, but binding values doesn't. At least not for me.  I made a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29212746/sphinxql-doesnt-work-with-prepared-statements